# Hazelcast IMap - Concurrent updates to the same key, different value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hazelcast

Without testing, because I'm stuck on a train and running out of battery...

I need to determine whether or not Hazelcast's IMap concurrent updates are thread safe updating the same key but different values of that key.

For example:

Let's say I have 2 different threads updating the same IMap key...

For all intents and purposes, this map looks like the following:

```
  key: {value1: 1, value2: 2}
```

One thread says,

```
  "I am updating value1 to 3"
```

the other thread says (at the same time)

```
  "I am updating value2 to 4".
```

How does Hazelcast handle this?

Will the final result look like the following?

```
  key: {value1: 3, value2: 4}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hazelcast uses partitions. Key is hashed to find the right partition for that entry.

Each partition is single-threaded, there is only one partition-thread handling each partition. So two update for a single key are handled by a single partition-thread.

If both updated keys land in the same partition, these operations will be sequential on a single partition-thread. If each key lands in a different partition - different threads will handle each update.

I don't really understand your notation:  `key: {value1: 1, value2: 2}` -> it looks like a nested map.

Also you say: `the same key but different values of that key.` -> in a map, each key has a single value only (unless the value is a collection or a map)

Comment: Yes, so in my example the "value" of the key is actually a map. You say that a partition is single-threaded. Does this mean Hazelcast will lock the key for me on each update of its value? I want to make sure I don't need to lock the key myself. I have different processes which will be updating different variables in the value map simultaneously. They will never update the same variable, however they will be updating the same key.

Comment: No need to lock. Each value update for a single key is single threaded. (does not matter what the value actually is).

Comment: how do I avoid having to lock if two threads try to create the key at the same time? In this case I would want the second thread to use my updating logic instead of my create logic.