# Working of single-threaded partition in Hazelcast for concurrent update request on the same key

Tags: java, concurrency, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Referring to answer given on [Hazelcast IMap - Concurrent updates to the same key, different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854870/hazelcast-imap-concurrent-updates-to-the-same-key-different-value) by @tom.bujok

It says "**Each partition is single-threaded, there is only one partition-thread handling each partition. So two update for a single key are handled by a single partition-thread. If both updated keys land in the same partition, these operations will be sequential on a single partition-thread**"

Let's say two update request is send to same key for the IMap, when single partition-thread is executing request 1, What will happen to request 2 for the same key? Does hazelcast puts **request 2 in some queue** or will **single partition-thread locks the partition** while executing request 1?

Comment: it waits in a queue

Comment: @ali Thank you for your reply. If there is some write operation executing on the key, read request for the same key is also blocked in the queue?

Comment: yes only a single operation can run on partition thread at a time so while a write operation (map.put) runs, the read operation waits